0 address instruction format for subtraction
Suppose we want to subtract (3-2) using the 0 address instruction format.The code will be
push 2
push 3
sub
or
push 3
push 2
sub
And what about other logical  instructions(NOT,AND,OR,XOR) , how can we apply them to 0 address instruction format?

what does the SUB instruction do? does it subtract the top of the stack from the second element or the opposite?
